# How do I assign a variable to a price in a while loop in order to get a subtotal?

Tags: python, string, while-loop, sum, user-input

I am working on a project but I can't seem to figure out this whole while loop thing. I am creating a little receipt program and I am able to get user input for the price of their items, however many they want to enter. But I cannot figure out how to tell the program to add all of the items they input to create a subtotal. Go easy on me, I am just a beginner. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

print("Welcome to Publix".center(80))


while(True):
    Price = float(input("Price of item: "))
    if(Price == -1):
        break





print("Thank you for shopping at Publix!".center(80))
#Tax = Subtotal * 0.065
```

Comment: Why my answer is not accepted?

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize your subtotal to 0 before loop and add the price everytime to subtotal.

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

print("Welcome to Publix".center(80))

Subtotal = 0
while(True):
    Price = float(input("Price of item: "))
    if(Price == -1):
        break

    Subtotal = Subtotal + Price





print Subtotal;
print("Thank you for shopping at Publix!".center(80))
#Tax = Subtotal * 0.065
```

Comment: I entered this into my code but I get no Subtotal after I enter -1 still

Comment: For that you need to print subtotal outside while loop

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable (`subtotal`) to accumulate the price values. You can add a [`try-except-else`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions) block to prevent wrong user input that cannot be converted to float from breaking your code. With this, your code is a little less buggy:

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')

print("Welcome to Publix".center(80))

subtotal = 0
while True:
    try:
        price = float(input("Price of item (enter -1 to stop): "))
        if price == -1:
            break
    except ValueError:
        print("The format of the price you entered is not acceptable")
    else:
        subtotal += price

print("Thank you for shopping at Publix!".center(80))
# tax = subtotal * 0.065
```

I suggest you store your prices using [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) for reasons relating to accuracy.